# Getting type error on Javascript two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I assign array[0][0] and array[0][1] with predefined variable and rest of the array with the data from php variable with for loop.

```
function getDistance(){
    var row = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('rows').innerHTML);
    var markers = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('markers').innerHTML);
    var distance = new Array(row);
    for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        distance[i] = new Array(2);
    }
    distance [0][0]= 16.78789;
    distance [0][1]= 96.15291;
    for(var i = 0; i<markers.length; i++){
        var latt = parseFloat(markers[i].latitude);
        var longt = parseFloat(markers[i].longitude);
        distance [i+1][0]= latt;
        distance [i+1][1]= longt;
    }
}
```

And this is where I get error in distance[i+1]. Its say distance[i+1] is undefined. The code is working fine if i assign distance[i][0] in for loop it means that I assign to distance[0][0] and [0][1]. Its doesn't allow me to start at array index 1.
This code is working there is nothing wrong with my variables I get all the variable I want only at array indexing getting error.

```
function getDistance(){
var row = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('rows').innerHTML);
var markers = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('markers').innerHTML);
var distance = new Array(row);
for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
  distance[i] = new Array(2);
}
for(var i = 0; i<markers.length; i++){
    var latt = parseFloat(markers[i].latitude);
    var longt = parseFloat(markers[i].longitude);
    distance [i][0]= latt;
    distance [i][1]= longt;
}
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `row` ... it better be one greater than the value of `markers.length` - because `i+1`

Comment: Javascript doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays, so of course the array you try to access does not exist if you didn't create it. did you create the i+1 array before trying to put elements in it? no.

Comment: I edited my question and its working fine and I also try with marker.length and get same error

Answer (score 1):

Array is zero index so you should compare to row-1

```
for (var i = 1; i < distance.length-1; i++) {
```

And also remove +1 in this lines

```
distance [i][0]= latt;
distance [i][1]= longt;
```

Comment: if i start loop at ``var i=1`` i can't get values from markers at index 0

Comment: You just fill the array here in this code while using it set i to 0

Comment: Thank u sir its working now but i need to use ``distance.length`` instant of  ``distance.length-1`` to get all my data.

Comment: Ok make it that but you have to check if i <distance.length if yes do the code else do nothing or return null

Comment: Or use while loop instead of for loop

Comment: Yes i checked all the data and length of array. Everything look fine. I used ``distance.length`` because i need one more room for my data. Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure "row" is a number after You parse that JSON, otherwise you have an array included a single "string" or "object" item at 0

```
var row = parseInt(JSON.parse(document.getElementById('rows').innerHTML));
```

and then check "distance" length

```
var distance = new Array(row);
console.log(distance)
```

Comment: I edited my question everything is fine in second code.

Comment: I checked your code on my pc and I added ***[{"a" : "1"},{"b" : "2"}]*** as the innerHtml of markers and rows, then distance[i+1] was undefined , so i changed rows to a fixed number in first loop ***for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {...}*** and problem solved. try this: ***for (var i = 0; i <= row.length; i++) {...}***

Comment: It working now i changed ``for(var i = 1;  i < distance.length; i++)`` and used ``distance[i][0]...``.